# SQLiteConnection read SMALLINT overflow

Tags: c#, sqlite, types, overflow

I read the [sqlite document datetype](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) that indicate
SMALLINT is affinity INTEGER.

[image]

I use the library below.
https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SQLite.Core/1.0.113.1

Common function

```
private static void TestSqlite(IDbConnection conn, string sql, Action<SQLiteCommand> action)
{
    conn.Open();
    var cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = sql;
    action?.Invoke(cmd);
    conn.Close();
}
```

(1) I create the TESTOVERFLOW table.

```
var cache = "Cache.db";
var conn = new SQLiteConnection($"Data Source={cache};Version=3;");
var sql1 = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TESTOVERFLOW(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, SHOWSMALLINT SMALLINT NOT NULL)";
TestSqlite(conn, sql1, (cmd) => cmd.ExecuteNonQuery());
```

(2) I insert the value 65535 which name is SHOWSMALLINT to the TESTOVERFLOW table.

```
var sql2 = "INSERT INTO TESTOVERFLOW(SHOWSMALLINT) VALUES (65535)";
TestSqlite(conn, sql2, (cmd) => cmd.ExecuteNonQuery());
```

(3) Read the TESTOVERFLOW table and select the colum SHOWSMALLINT. I get the value -1.

```
var sql3 = "SELECT * FROM TESTOVERFLOW";
TestSqlite(conn, sql3, (cmd) =>
{
    var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{reader[0]} | {reader[1]}");
        // 1 | -1
    }
});
```

(3.1) Use the sqlite3 command to read the TESTOVERFLOW table and I got the SHOWSMALLINT value is 65535 see the below picture.
[image]

(4) why I use the C# SQLiteconnection read the value is -1 not the 65535? 
the 65535 and -1 to binary is below

```
1111 1111 1111 1111(2)(unsign) => 65535(10)
1111 1111 1111 1111(2)(sign)   =>    -1(10)
```

The SMALLINT is affinity INTEGER. So I think read value must be 65535 beacuse I insert the value 65535 is correct not show the error.

I use sqlite command read value is 65535 but I use Sqliteconnection seems cast the value to -1.

Is SQLiteConnection read datatype not follow the sqlite document type?

Comment: `65535` would be the maximum value of an unsigned 16 bit integer. That said, the documentation seems to indicate that `smallint` would be interpreted as a signed 64 bit integer.

Comment: Sounds like this sqliteconnection thing is being too smart for its own good and parsing a table definition itself and doing its own interpretation of types.

Comment: It is singened int and size 2 byte ,so max value 32767

Comment: @AluanHaddad thanks for answer. but why I use the sqlite3 command to read value is correct but use C# SQLiteConnection read value is incorrect. If smallint is interpreted as a signed 64 bit integer why C# SQLiteConnection read value is overflow.

Comment: @Shawn I guess you're right.But I can't understand why happen to this.

Comment: @LDS but why I use sqlite command read the vlaue is bigger than 32767 and does't overflow. I guess the SQLiteconnection read the value is use singened int and size 2 byte and does't follow the sqlite document datatype.

Comment: the range is - 32768 to +32767

Comment: @LDS Could you provide the link that indicate the smallint range is -32768 to +32767 ? I only found the smallint range is -32768 to +32767 in SQL not the sqlite.

Comment: look the calculatio 2 bytes = 16bits  = 256x256 /2 is the range from negative to positive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I write the test project for the SQLiteConnection. 
Test [System.Data.SQLite.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SQLite.Core/1.0.113.1) library that use the IDataReader to read value and list the sqlite data type in the below.

```
Range is 0 ~ 255, 0 ~ (2^8 -1)
TINYINT

Range is -32768 ~ 32767, (-2^15) ~ (2^15 -1)
SMALLINT

Range is -2147483648 ~ 2147483647, (-2^31) ~ (2^31 -1)
INT
MEDIUMINT

Range is over than -9223372036854775808 ~ 9223372036854775807, (-2^63) ~ (2^63 -1) that will cast to the exponent value
INTEGER
INT2
INT8
BIGINT
UNSIGNED BIG INT
```

If you are interesting in the result, you can reference the [test project](https://github.com/changemyminds/Test-SQLiteConnection-Read-Datatypes).